# What video output formats are supported on the Nintendo Gamecube?

Tags: nintendo-gamecube

I have a composite output cable for my Gamecube, but it would be nice if it supported a higher quality output, such as S-Video or Component.  Does the Gamecube have output support for these outputs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some Gamecubes (DOL-001) support Component out with the proper (discontinued) cable.

http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/systems/nintendogamecube/component.jsp

Most will support the (also discontinued) S-Video Cable

http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/systems/nintendogamecube/hook_svideo.jsp

And all should support Coax and Composite.

Answer (score 1):

Note that **most US (NTSC) Gamecube games support up to 480p via component cable** (I use an Australian cube with NTSC games via a freeloader disc).

As McKay says, depending which model of gamecube you have, there *may* be a separate port on the back for the proprietary component cable (some later models were made without one, and I think in Japan there was a different port altogether). If you have the port, you can get one of these cables from eBay (US$50-100). There may even be a chance of still getting one from Nintendo direct in some countries (unlikely, but more like $35, so might be worth the call - I bought mine long after the Gamecube was no longer being sold).

If you don't want to spend the money though (or don't have the special port), the next best thing is a cheap third party S-Video cable (that fits the existing AV port, try eBay - less than $10 shipped).

(I actually use an old (but very high-end) 21 inch CRT computer monitor (set to RGB colour mode) through the component cable and a digital signal transcoder box. The picture quality is fantastic.)

Comment: wow, those things sell for $50+ on ebay now? i need to sell mine then... i use the wii if i want to play GC games on the flatscreen...

Comment: also it should be noted that the 480p used by GC is only 4:3. a few games support 16:9 (eternal darkness does, i know), but they aren't actually outputting more pixels--they're just squishing 16:9 into a 4:3 output which gets stretched back to 16:9 by your tv

Comment: Just FYI, the current eBay price for original Nintendo GameCube component cables is now running $150 - $200.

Answer (score -1):

I think the Wii uses the same video port, and so you might be able to use the Wii Component cable in a gamecube.

Comment: wrong, the wii and gamecube cables are completely incompatible!